# How to access "Starting building" in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm triggering another job through Jenkins pipeline. I need to find the URL of the job, before the job completes execution. Below works only after the job gets completed

```groovy
result1 = build job: "$jobName", parameters: paramList
print result1.absoluteUrl
```

Basically i'm trying to achieve something like below

```groovy
result1="NotSet"
parallel JobTrigger:{result1=build job: "$jobName", parameters: paramList}, 
checkJob:{
    while(result1.equals("NotSet")){
        Thread.sleep (3*1000)
         print "Job is still not set"
     }
triggeredJobURL=result1.absoluteUrl
print "triggeredJobURL: " + triggeredJobURL

emailext body: "Downstream job triggered URL:$triggeredJobURL", subject: 'Downstream job triggered', to: "${EMAIL_ADDRESS}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`result1` is a variable with [RunWrapper](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html) type.
By default (see [wait](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#code-build-code-build-a-job) ) a parent job waits completion of a downstream build. In that case the return value of the step is an `RunWrapper` object.
If `wait:false`, and in that case there is currently no return value.

In comments of this [Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48475) describe this problem.

You can send email from a downstream job (needs script approval):

```groovy
triggeredJobURL = current.build.rawbuild.parent.url
emailext body: "Downstream job triggered URL:$triggeredJobURL", subject: 'Downstream job triggered', to: "${EMAIL_ADDRESS}"
```